# Do UK universities have a special obligation to advertise jobs externally?

Tags: university, united-kingdom, legal-issues, policy, recruiting

I often hear it said that all jobs have to be advertised externally before anyone can be appointed to an academic post in a UK university. However, this rule about having to advertise externally is certainly not true in general in industry where the only obligation one might have to avoid discrimination claims is to advertise the job internally.

Is there a special obligation on a UK university through some public sector regulations, maybe, to advertise all jobs externally?  I'm asking about UK universities in particular.

Comment: I don't know about the UK, but in the US this is often the case.  It can make for very frustrating interactions when people apply for a position that is de facto already earmarked for a particular candidate.

Comment: @jakebeal Is there a specific law that relates to universities in the US in this regard that doesn't apply to purely commercial enterprises?

Comment: There is also an interesting twist where the person has previously been doing the same job but on a fixed term contract.  It's not clear to me if a new position is created (which might require advertising) if they are then made permanent.

Comment: @Lembik See Bill Barth's answer for an example. It will vary state to state, however.

Comment: Even when not required by law, many institutions adopt this requirement as  a matter of internal policy, which may require high-level approval to waive.

Comment: @NateEldredge My suspicion is that you have hit the nail on the head but I am interested if there might be some public sector regulation which actually requires jobs to be advertised externally.

Comment: In the United States, at least, there are also very specific federal requirements about public posting of jobs if the person being hired will need a work visa such as an H-1B visa.

Comment: Yes, and sometimes to prevent things like nepotism, etc....

Comment: In which country?  You're asking about public sector regulations, so the answer is going to be very different for different countries.  As such, the question currently seems too broad.  I suggest that you edit the question to scope it more narrowly by specifying a particular jurisdiction that you care about.

Comment: Most French universities have actually a non-internal recruitment policy. More or less enforced depending on the field and the particular department.

Comment: @D.W. My question is about the UK (see the question itself and the tag "united kingdom").

Comment: In Germany public state-financed universities (AFAIK any other public authority too) have to publish job offers externally. (there exist some exceptions for religious institutions, they fall under different laws)

Comment: Marshall, thank you for the clarification.  In the future, you should include that in the question, as it's easy to overlook, otherwise.  (And as you can see from some of the answers, some respondents didn't seem to realize this.)  I've edited the question for you this time, but just letting you know for the future.  Thank you!

Answer (score 7):

I think you are misunderstanding how academic job searches work in the UK. All jobs, and I believe this is not specific to universities, must be advertised internally first to individuals in the "redundancy pool". If, and only if, there is no one in the redundancy pool that can meet the minimum requirements with 6 months of training can the job be advertised externally. The redundency pool is available to people, I think, from 3 months before their contract ends until 3 months afterwards.

Current employees not in the redundancy pool, can get prompted within the same job family without having to advertise the job at all. At my university there is no system for moves, lateral or upwards, across job families. That said, if you really want someone, you can regrade and reclassify them.

Comment: Is it the same for state and public universities?

Comment: Thank you for this. I understand about the redundancy pool and how it works. As an example of my question, consider a lecturer on a fixed term contract who is more than 3 months from the end of their contract. Is the university legally entitled to simply give them a permanent position or do they really have to advertise it externally under some law or regulation?

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano in the UK there are really only public universities. I m not sure about the few private univeraities, but I think the redundancy pool is an EU thing.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano The laws around redundancy that StrongBad refers to are part of UK national statute. They are the same for private and public universities.

Comment: @marshall I believe after 4 years on a fixed term contract in the same job you become permanent. When my department wants to convert someone from fixed to permanent we just extend the fixed term contract past the 4 year mark.

Comment: @StrongBad My understanding is that some UK universities get round this by claiming that when the specifically allocated funding for the fixed term post has run out then there is a legitimate redundancy.

Comment: @marshall just because a job is permanent does not mean they cannot make you redundant. I am not sure where you are going with this.  If you have a new question you should ask it as a new question.

Comment: @StrongBad Sorry for any confusion (and you are right there is another good related question to ask here).  I just meant that some UK universities don't interpret extending a contract beyond 4 years as making any practical difference at all. You acquire unfair dismissal rights after 2 years after all so you have to go through a redundancy process either way.

Comment: @marshall Aberdeen University tried this and lost their case at an employment tribunal.  You can read about it here: http://www.xperthr.co.uk/editors-choice/university-researcher-on-three-successive-fixed-term-contracts-declared-permanent-employee/104490/

Answer (score 3):

Yes, in my state (Texas), there's a [law](http://www.statutes.legis.state.tx.us/Docs/GV/htm/GV.656.htm) that all government vacancies in positions (including jobs at state-run, public universities) must be posted publicly for at least 10 business days unless the position is to be filled by an internal candidate. It is often [flouted openly](http://www.ktxs.com/news/texas-ag-fills-several-top-jobs-without-public-postings/33996554).

Comment: This seems the opposite of what the OP is asking about. He is claiming that even if the positions will be filled with an internal candidate,  that you still need to post it publically.

Comment: Yes that is right. UK universities seem to claim that they have to advertise all jobs externally (except for the rule about people in the redundancy pool pointed out by StrongBad). I just found http://www.theguardian.com/higher-education-network/blog/2014/aug/01/academics-anonymous-advertising-research-posts-waste-of-time  which does say "Yes, this whole situation comes down to fairness and having an open competition so that the best candidate gets the job. Universities are not legally obliged to advertise posts externally, but most choose to do so."

Comment: In addition, the question is apparently asking specifically about UK universities, so Texas laws aren't relevant to the question -- in other words, this doesn't answer the question.  (I realize that the original version was a bit unclear, but the original version was also probably too broad for that same reason.)

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the country, state or the university.  Some university have their own policy. Some country or state may also have some rules about whether a university should advertise jobs externally. If you are not sure, you may contact someone from a given university to know how it works there.